# 3 tabbed login form validating

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a 3 tabbed user form where one tab is for "registering", another tab for "login" and a third tab for "forgot".  The default is "login" and for the most part that all works fine.  My problem is that when the user clicks 1 of the other tabs, say "register", and fills in the information and clicks "submit", the page seems to refresh and jump back to the default, which is login.  I get why it is doing that because the default radio button is setup that way.  How do I stay on that page and ensure it has done proper validating individually?  I know I can create 3 individual pages, but I am trying to make it as efficient as possible and this seems logical.  I have tried using "sessions" but everything is so bloated.  Is there a simple way to do this validating on "current" tab?  Ajax? Javascript? JQuery?  I have tried for 2 weeks now and am almost defeated.

https://codepen.io/lepew/pen/pPQWQG

```
<div class="sign_Area">
<input type="radio" name="tabGroup1" id="rad1" class="tab1"/>
<label for="rad1">REGISTER</label>
<input type="radio" name="tabGroup1" id="rad2" class="tab2" checked="checked"/>
<label for="rad2">LOGIN</label>
<input type="radio" name="tabGroup1" id="rad3" class="tab3"/>
<label for="rad3">FORGOT</label>
<div class="tab1"><!-- REGISTER -->
    <div class="sign_Case">
        REGISTER
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <form action = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method = "post">
            <label>Login ID  :</label><input type = "text" name = "new_name" class = "box"/><br /><br />
            <label>Email  :</label><input type = "text" name = "new_email" class = "box"/><br /><br />
            <label>Password  :</label><input type = "text" name = "new_pass" class = "box"/><br /><br />
            <input type = "Submit" value = "Submit" name = "Submit1"/><br />
        </form>
        <br/>
        <br/>
    </div><!-- end of #sign_Case -->
</div><!-- end of TAB1 -->
<div class="tab2"><!-- LOGIN -->
    <div class="sign_Case">
        LOGIN ...
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <form action = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method = "post">
            <label>UserName  :</label><input type = "text" name = "username" class = "box"/><br /><br />
            <label>Password  :</label><input type = "password" name = "password" class = "box" /><br/><br />
            <input type = "Submit" value = "Submit" name = "Submit2"/><br />
        </form>
        <br/>
        <br/>
    </div><!-- end of #sign_Case -->
</div><!-- end of TAB2 -->
<div class="tab3"><!-- FORGOT -->
    <div class="sign_Case">
        FORGOT PASSWORD ...
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <form action = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method = "post">
            <label>Login1 ID  :</label><input type = "text" name = "forgot_name1" class = "box"/><br /><br />
            <label>Login2 ID  :</label><input type = "text" name = "forgot_name2" class = "box"/><br /><br />
            <input type = "Submit" value = "Submit" name = "Submit3"/><br />
        </form>
        <br/>
        <br/>
    </div><!-- end of #sign_Case -->
</div><!-- end of TAB3 -->
<br/>
<br/>
```

Comment: so you want to add this code into tabs?

Comment: It's because when you submit, your response causes a full page reload and it doesn't know what tab to go back to.  Ajax (using vanilla JS or jQuery) is a good solution here or you can hack it by also submitting which tab the user was on in the form (hidden field) and then use JS to pop back to that tab on page load.